# What is “Lacrimosa” in music?

Tags: notation

What is the mood / emotion most closely associated with the Italian term “Lacrimosa” used in music notation?

Comment: By "in music notation" do you mean that you see the word _lacrymosa_ used as a direction rather than as the title of a piece or in the text of a vocal piece?

Comment: If you're asking because you found it in a piece of music, it might be helpful to say which one and add a picture if possible.

Comment: You asked about the mood and emotion associated with the word. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwaD_lOgoCY) is Britten's very lachrymal setting. From his War Requiem.

Comment: [Lachrymose, adj.:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lachrymose)  Tearful, sorrowful, sad, pertaining to tears, weeping, causing tears or crying.

Answer (score 4):

"Lacrimosa" is the latin term for "weeping" or "mournful". It is notably used in Mozart's Requiem in D minor, and also a part of the Roman Catholic Requiem Mass Dies Irae sequence.

Comment: More literally, _lacrimosa_ means "tearful."  Also, the _dies irae_ sequence is specific to the requiem mass.

Answer (score 4):

*lacrimosa* is the female pendant to *lacrimoso* or latin *lacrimosus*, derived from *lacrima* (the tear). So *lacrimosa* is a female adjective meaning *with tears, tearful*. Usually for a playing instruction you’d expect to find the male form, so *lacrimoso*. But it is not really an instruction commonly used in music. If anything you’d use this as an indication to play a part particularly lamenting, but usually you’d use *lamentoso* for that.

And if we talk about a text passage:
The most famous text passage use of *lacrimosa* is most likely the part of the *dies iræ* sequence of the catholic requiem mass, wherein it has a totally different context:

> Lacrimosa dies illa
> Qua resurget ex favilla
> Judicandus homo reus.
> Huic ergo parce, Deus:
> Pie Jesu Domine,
> Dona eis requiem. Amen.

which means somewhat like

> Tearful that day
> when from the fiery ashes shall rise
> the guilty man to be judged.
> Therefore spare him, God:
> Pious Lord Jesus
> give them rest. Amen.

So just going for a lamenting emotion just because the text contains *lacrimosa* can be totally wrong, depending on context. But if we take the Mozart canon:

> Lacrimoso son’io
> perduto ho l’idol mio.

which is

> Tearful I am,
> I’ve lost my love.

Here we get a lamenting meaning. So it is not possible to give a general emotion for this single word.

Answer (score 2):

Since the other answers only refer to Requiem (death mass), I'd like to supplement the beginning of another Christian and frequently encountered text, the **Stabat mater**, even if it does not provide a different meaning:

> Stabat mater dolorosa
> iuxta crucem **lacrimosa**,
> dum pendebat filius;

referring to Virgin Mary weeping (or tearful) below the cross, where Jesus is hanging.